# Running a Docker container on Apache2

Tags: docker, flask, apache2

I have a server where I am hosting several apps. They are all accessible on their own subdirectories through the same server name, so my app `foo` is found at `www.servername.com/foo` and `bar` is found at `www.servername.com/bar` and so on. Most of these apps are Flask apps with the route and the static files configured through apache `VirtualHost *:443` to run SSL.

I have been given another Flask app, `baz`, to run on the server which has been configured to spin up into two Docker containers, one for the app and one for the database. I have managed to adjust my apache .conf file as follows:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.servername.com

    # some additional config for my other apps, in Directories and static aliases

    ProxyPreserveHost On
    SSLProxyEngine On
    <Proxy *>
        Allow from *
    </Proxy>
    ProxyPass "/baz" "http://<IP address>:5000"
    ProxyPassReverse "/baz" "http://<IP address>:5000"
</VirtualHost>
```

I think the configuration is reaching the running container, because when I go to `www.servername.com/baz` it redirects to `www.servername.com/login`. It *should* redirect to `www.servername.com/baz/login`, but clearly something hasn't gone right. **How can I get the proxy to correctly direct all `baz` traffic through the `/baz` subdirectory?**

Additionally, I can manually navigate to `www.servername.com/baz/login` to see the login page for the `baz` app, but it appears not to have loaded the CSS, so I assume the static files are not being loaded. **Do I need to set up an alias for these static files too, like I do with my other non-Docker Flask apps?** If so, the standard format that I usually use:

```
Alias baz/static /path/to/baz/static
```

is not working. On a whim, I also tried something weirder just to see if it would work:

```
Alias "baz/static" "http://<IP address>:5000/static"
```

but this didn't work either. Perhaps it will be fixed by addressing the proxy routing issue above, but how can I make the static files accessible to the `baz` app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the website that is running under `/baz` doesn't know that's where it's running and so is rendering URLs under `/` instead. You have a couple of options:

1. Use subdomains: `baz.servername.com`. Then the Flask apps can just use `/` freely without conflicts.
2. Make the Flask apps aware of where they're serving, so your Flask app is configured to use `/baz` to prefix every URL it serves.